# What ports are advised to use for secure mail?

Tags: ssl, mail-transport-agent

I have installed postfix and dovecot mail server.
My clients use The Bat software to send/receive mails.
They use standart 25 and 110 ports.

Now I want to secure my connection, and I want to ask these questions:

1. What ports should I use instead of 25 and 110 ports to secure my
   connection? What is usually used?
2. If I secure my connection, will other mail servers receive my letters?
   For example, if I send mails via 25 port STARTTLS, will they receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard ports for normal (in-the-clear) and secure/encrypted communications, by protocol:

```
IMAP: normal 143, secure 993
POP:  normal 110, secure 995
SMTP: normal 25,  secure 465/587
```

Confusingingly SMTP has two secure ports. You're supposed to use 465 for SSL/TLS and 587 STARTTLS ([see the last section of this page](https://www.fastmail.com/help/technical/ssltlsstarttls.html)) though it's not mandated.

Addressing your second question: these are the port numbers of the server, not your machine, so if one of these is not accessible you can't use it. Also, these ports are used to secure communications between yourself and the mail server you send your mail to. It is not related to how a mail relay delivers mail to the server at the final destination.

Comment: If I send email via port 587, will other mail server accept my mails(if they are still on ports 25 and 110)?

Comment: Well, no, if a server doesn't have a secure port open you can't use that port. That's what these numbers are: the server port not ports on your machine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand a little. Let's say I am organization A and I have mail server (SMTP with starttls 587, and 995 port for POP3S). I want to send an email to organization B. Organization B has mail server, which uses standart ports 25 and 110. Can I send letters to them?

Comment: I know, let's say I have opened port 587 and port 995 on my server. But, should organization B also open that ports on their mail server?

Comment: Please add TCP to the ports.

Comment: "I believe you should avoid using STARTTLS with the nonsecure ports." -- Actually, I thought the exact opposite. Even the link you give states that "you should have 1 port that starts off as plaintext, but the client can upgrade the connection to an SSL/TLS encrypted one. This is what STARTTLS was created to do."

Comment: Dear users, please answer me, if I open that tcp ports on my server, should organization B also open that ports? But they use standard tcp 25 and 110 ports. Will they recieve my letters?

Comment: Your use of 587 has nothing to do with Org B not having port 587 open. It can receive on port 25 if a relay is willing to talk to it on port 25. You use 587 to secure communications between yourself and the mail server you send your mail to.

Comment: @BLayer, thank you very much, so it is none of our business to care about organization B. We just have to secure our connections, our server.

Comment: @BLayer, what? TLS is end-to-end. In the sense that it's not packet-level, that is. It's not end-to-end for the email message, since it might pass a number of servers and thus a number of SMTP connections. For that, you'd need to use GPG or such.

Comment: I'm talking about establishing a secure connection immediately as opposed to upgrading a plain-text conversation...I've read of nasty bugs that fail to secure but continue anyways..in the clear. I'm just going to remove that line since it's not directly related to the question and it's causing confusion.

Comment: @BLayer, can you give your skype id? I need your help about mail server

Comment: Ok thank you all. Firstly, I will try your methods, and if it works, I will mark correct answer.

Comment: Sure. Good luck!

Comment: @BLayer, it worked when I forced to use tcp port 587 with STARTTLS, and next question, can I force to use IMAPS for receiving mails? Should I generate new certificates for Dovecot imaps? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to secure the communication, not switch to other ports.

TLS is a protocol to encrypt communication. In order to be able to use TLS, however, both sides of the conversations need to agree on doing so; otherwise one side will expect communication in the clear, and the other side will expect encrypted communication, and everything will go wrong.

Ensuring that both sides use the same (i.e., either encrypted or unencrypted) type of communication can be done in two ways:

- You support an "unencrypted" version of the protocol on one port, and an "encrypted" version of the protocol on the other. Clients that connect to the "encrypted" port will start the TLS handshake immediately after connecting, and no unencrypted communication will take place
- You support a "please upgrade the connection to TLS" command on the unencrypted port. This is the `STARTTLS` way of doing things. In this method, clients connect to the unencrypted port, then send (in the clear) a command to the server to upgrade to TLS. From then on, everything will be encrypted.

Both sides have their upsides and downsides, and there isn't really a "best" way. The good news is that you *can* do both at the same time; most IMAP and SMTP software supports being run in both modes in parallel.

Additionally, you should take care to understand the difference between mail *submission* and mail *delivery*:

- Submission is when your clients want to send an email to third parties and need an "outgoing SMTP" server (you). They connect to the server, are authenticated in some way (e.g., by way of a username and password, or by connecting IP address, or by some other means), and then use the SMTP protocol to submit emails for delivery. It is then up to your server to ensure that the emails in question end up at their final destination. In order to provide a useful service to your customers, submission clients *must* be allowed to send email to the whole Internet. Port 587 is provided as a standard port for submission clients, but you can choose any you like if you so prefer.
- Delivery is for when your server is the final destination for an email sent by a *third party*. Since the sending server does not require any client relationship with your server, it cannot be authenticated. Instead, it looks up the address for your server through the MX record in the DNS, and then connects to your server on port 25. It delivers the emails to your server, and expects you to ensure it ends up with the final recipient. In order to avoid becoming a SPAM relay, delivery clients *must not* be allowed to send email to the whole Internet. Port 25 is the *only* allowed port for delivery clients.

If `STARTTLS` is enabled on port 25, TLS can be used for delivery clients. If you use port 587, you *should* default to unencrypted communication and provide the `STARTTLS` command. If you want to use the older method of "connect with immediate TLS handshake", you should use port 465 instead.