# How to configure and force users to use IMAP?

Tags: imap

I have installed mail server with postfix and dovecot. 
My clients use The Bat email client software. 
While sending mails, they use tcp port 587 with STARTTLS. 
And I disabled tcp port 25 for sending mails in firewall (in server).

Now, they receive mails via tcp port 110 POP3 protocol. 
I want to use IMAP or IMAPS for receiving mails for my clients. 
And I totally want to disable POP3 protocol.

1) I tried to change port number to 143 for receiving mails in "The Bat", but it cannot receive mails. How can I do it right?  
2) Should I reconfigure dovecot for using IMAP/S only? 
3) Is my idea is right?

PS: I opened port 143 on my server in firewall.

Comment: Please link to your previous question if they are related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414476/what-ports-are-advised-to-use-for-secure-mail

Comment: There wasn't told about IMAP/IMAPS and switching from POP3 to IMAP

Comment: Well... it should work like a charm with proper configuration. So you must have a misconfiguration between postfix and dovecot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your dovecot configuration is done right.
[(how to)](https://debian-administration.org/article/275/Setting_up_an_IMAP_server_with_dovecot)

1. Depending on a version check if you have imap protocol enabled in:
   /etc/dovecot.conf
   /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
   OR
   /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf
2. Than check if dovecot is listening on 143
3. Than check it from outside, that the port is really opened.
4. Setup the client [(how to)](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9619/2175/email-account-setup-in-the-bat-email-client-smtpimappop3)

---

**EDIT:** Issue was solved, problem was on clients side (Bat email client)

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71246/discussion-on-answer-by-petr-how-to-configure-and-force-users-to-use-imap).